# How can i see the result in this async module.exports in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have this module in my code that i need to debug. Its in a file we can call **test.js** that is called by GCP cloud scheduler.

```
const run = require("../../run");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  await run(false);
  res.send("done");
};
```

I want to log the res to see whats going on. Something like this:

```
console.log('hello');
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  await run(false);

  console.log(res)

  res.send("done");
};
console.log('world');
```

But im not getting that console.log. I will get

```
hello
world
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: provide more log

Comment: Updated the question, sorry

Comment: How do you know the exported function is actually getting called? It seems like it isn't. (Or that `await run(false)` doesn't finish so that you never get to the `console.log` line)

Comment: I am so sure console.log(res) won't log between ``hello`` and ``world``. because async code won't run as sync code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will see "Hello" "World" first, because it will print when you import the module in some file.
the console.logs are in the module "global scope"!!

I did't quite get you code, but it seams to me that you're not calling the function, just exporting!

Try something like:

**requestfile.js**

```
const run = require('../../run');
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    const resp = await run(false);
    console.log(resp)
    res.send("done");
};
```

**testfile.js**

```
const req = require('./requestfile');
async function main () {
  await req();
}
main();
```